# How to merge two dfs based on a substring of the strings in a column and insert values of another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have the following dfs:

`data`:

| ZIP code | urbanisation |
| --- | --- |
| 1111AA |  |
| 3916HV |  |

`reference`:

| ZIP code category | urbanisation |
| --- | --- |
| 1111 | High |
| 3916 | Medium |

So the urbanisation in my data set is empty and I need to fill it using a measure of urbanisation I found online. I want to:

- Match column `reference["ZIP code category"]` with the first 4 digits of `data["ZIP code"]`, but I cannot change the actual ZIP codes. That is, I want to match based on a substring, for example by using `data["ZIP code"].str[:4]`.
- For every match paste the corresponding value of `reference["urbanisation"]` in `data["urbanisation"]`

I tried this as follows:

```
pd.merge(
    data, reference,
    left_on=['ZIP code', data["ZIP code"].str[:4]],
    right_on=['ZIP code category', reference["ZIP code category"]]
)
```

However, this code is not correct and I do not know how to produce the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `join`:

```
data['urbanisation'] = data['ZIP code'].str[:4].map(
                           reference.astype({'ZIP code category': str})
                                    .set_index('ZIP code category')['urbanisation'])
print(data)

# Output
  ZIP code urbanisation
0   1111AA         High
1   3916HV       Medium
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution, which is based on [`pandas.DataFrame.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
out = df1.set_index(df1['ZIP code'].str.replace(r'\D', ''))
out.update(df2.set_index(df2['ZIP code category'].astype(str)))
out.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
  ZIP code urbanisation
0   1111AA         High
1   3916HV       Medium
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I should replace df1 with data and df2 with reference right?

Comment: Yes, @Xtiaan: `df1` corresponds to your first dataframe, and `df2` to your second dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

You can create new helper column `ZIP code category` by first 4 values and also `ZIP code category` convert to strings (if necessary) and use left join:

```
df = pd.merge(data.drop('urbanisation',axis=1), reference,
              left_on=data["ZIP code"].str[:4],
              right_on=reference["ZIP code category"].astype(str)
               ).drop(['key_0','ZIP code category'], axis=1, errors='ignore')
print (df)
  ZIP code urbanisation
0   1111AA         High
1   3916HV       Medium
```